# Exploding a json array into individual druid rows using flatten spec

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I have been trying to explode a json array into multiple rows in Druid using flatten spec.

Is it possible to get the below json array into druid using flatten spec or any other method ?

```
[{"name":"test","age":21},{"name":"test2","age":22}]
```

In Druid as below

```
name    |    age
test1   |     21
test2   |     22
```

Also, I have looked at the below page and could see that support for processing of batch of records in single kafka event is possible on druid ?

https://github.com/apache/druid/issues/4373

Can we explode a single kafka event with multiple records in it and save it to druid without using any pre-processors ?